# Не собирается ядро Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel

Пытаюсь собрать ядро 4.8, но получаю следующею ошибку:

```
allex@allex-ubuntu:~/linux-4.8$ make
CHK     include/config/kernel.release
Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
Makefile:1048: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «prepare-compiler-check»
make: *** [prepare-compiler-check] Ошибка 1
```

Build-essential стоит,ubuntu 16.10, версия gcc:

```
allex@allex-ubuntu:~/linux-4.8$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu26' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu26)
```

Нашёл что обычно, такая ошибка на версиях gcc ниже 4.8, но у меня то стоит 6.2.0.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём тут проблема, заранее спасибо!

Comment: А у вас нет старых версий gcc в системе?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel

Special note as of Kernel 4.4 and if compiling using Ubuntu 14.04 (I don't know about 15.10), with an older version of the c compiler: It can not compile with CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG.

scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG

Answer (score 1):

Часто такая ошибка появляется, если нет заголовочных файлов.
Попробуйте так:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Ээээ, виноват, `uname -r` надо в кавычках выполнения ``(за буквой ё которые)``

Comment: Нет, заголовочные файлы стоят.